# Strange logic in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a strange Case building MySql Query:

Here it is.

1. I Need to Sort the Results based on first_name and last_name
2. My expected result is using CONCAT(first_name, last_name)  in ORDER BY

But i am restricted to not to use CONCAT in ORDER BY. Is there a way i can Build the Query

RAW SQL :

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, last_name) 
FROM users 
ORDER BY CONCAT(first_name, last_name)
```

Cases: first_name can be empty

Example

```
First Name           Last Name
A                    B
                     B
C                    D
```

Now i need the SOrt Order as

```
AB 
B
CD
```

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT(first_name, last_name) FROM users ORDER BY 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT full_name FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(first_name, last_name) AS full_name FROM users
) AS tmp ORDER BY full_name
```

Answer (score 0):

if the blank are `NULL`, use `COALESCE`

```
ORDER BY CONCAT(COALESCE(first_name,''), COALESCE(last_name,''))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc745/1)
- [COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
order by (case when FirstName is NULL or FirstName = '' then LastName else FirstName end),
         LastName
```

Less seriously, you could use `concat_ws()` . . . just like `concat()` but different.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can sort by column alias:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, last_name) AS full_name 
FROM users ORDER BY full_name
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90819/1).